Terraform: how to access a resource in module for output?
How to access a resource for output, for exampe ec2 instance: aws_instance.splat_lab.ebs_block_device.*.volume_id
Tried notation module.module-name.path-to-resource, i.e. module.webserver-cas12.aws_instance.splat_lab.ebs_block_device.*.volume_id but module.module-name is empty.
How to output from module or how to inbuild output of a speciific resource to module?

To properly output a specific resource, like an EC2 instance's volume_id, from a module in Terraform, here are some things you need to check:
First, make sure the module itself defines the output you need. You can define the output for the volume_id in the outputs.tf file within the module.
output "ebs_volume_ids" {
  value = aws_instance.splat_lab.ebs_block_device.*.volume_id
}

This will output all the volume_ids associated with the ebs_block_device of the EC2 instance resource inside the module.
In your root module (where you call the module), you can reference this output using the following syntax:
module "webserver" {
  source = "./path-to-your-module"

  # Other variables you may pass to the module
}

output "webserver_ebs_volume_ids" {
  value = module.webserver.ebs_volume_ids
}

Make sure the module name (webserver) matches the name you use in your module block.
Notes based on your specific situation:

If module.webserver is empty, ensure that the module's source is defined properly, and that the module is correctly pulling the resources you expect.
Terraform modules encapsulate resources, so you need to define outputs explicitly to access the internal resource attributes like volume_id.
To confirm the resource exists within the module, use terraform plan or terraform state list to inspect the state and see if the resource is being created as expected.

